# Maintain cell reference when deleting rows in the original table - Google Sheets/Excel

Tags: google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that basically shows the data of another table. The problem is: I have some script procedures going in the original table that envolve deleting rows and when it happens I lose the reference to the place of my row.

How can I fix this?

Already tried this:   ='INVENTORY'!A3='  »»»»»»»»»  INVENTORY'!$A$3

Answer (score 2):

When an entire row or column is deleted either manually or by script, Google Sheets replaces all the formulas that refer to it as `#REF`.

You can use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) to make a reference truly static: either manually, or by script as well.

**Formula Sample:**

```
=INDIRECT("Form!B7")*INDIRECT("Form!F7")'
```

**Script Sample:**

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
   
  // get range and formula
  var dataRange = datasheet.getRange("G1");
  var formula = dataRange.getFormula();

  // delete row
  formSS.deleteRow(7);

  // redefine formula
  formula = '=INDIRECT("Form!B7")*INDIRECT("Form!F7")';
  
  // set new formula
  dataRange.setFormula(formula);
}
```

Comment: Theres really no alternative with formulas?

Comment: Edited my answer. You can use INDIRECT to retain the reference, but you would need to encompass each cell reference one by one.